# error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,SOCKET &,SOCKADDR *,unsigned int>'

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, operators

in this function I see this error
error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Binder' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
void WComm::startServer(int port)
{
    // Connect to a server.
    con.sin_family = AF_INET;
    con.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
    con.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (bind(m_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&con, sizeof(con)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect.\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Listen on the socket.
    if (listen(m_socket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    printf("Error listening on socket.\n");
}
```

anyone cane help me?
thanks.

Comment: Try `::bind` in place of plain `bind`. And get out of the habit of `using namespace std;`. The compiler thinks you are calling `std::bind` from the standard library, rather then `bind` from Winsock API (the former is a better match in overload resolution, due to the latter's signed/unsigned mismatch in the last parameter).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Igor was explaining "try **::bind** instead of the plain **bind**. The compiler thinks you are calling std::bind from the *Standard Library*, rather then bind from *Winsock API*."

It worked for me.